# VLOOKUP and Transform a table inside the formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have this table:

[image: Excel Table]

What I want to achieve here is to **get the last three character of the lookup** value and **transform the table being referenced in VLOOKUP into their last three character** without having to create a new excel table filled with last three character of the table being referenced.

Here's how I tried it but since `RIGHT(A:A,3)` cannot be done, is there any alternative way to code this in one straight line?

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(B2,3),RIGHT(A:A,3),1,FALSE)
```

Comment: So effectively you want to perform a search on `*tin`? and return the first value that fits the criteria?

Comment: yup, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your explaination, it looks like you need to use wildcards. Within `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&RIGHT(B2,3),A:A,1,FALSE)
```

But I would suggest get in the habit of using `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo, since it's faster:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&RIGHT(B2,3),A:A,0))
```

Comment: Oh nice, it's similar to a regex. Thanks for this one, I'll accept your answer once the site allows me